# Inject value in a spring bean from constants java file

Tags: java, spring

I have an application in which in a spring bean, value is being injected from a property file.
I want to inject value from a constants.java file.
What changes are do I need to make.

Spring bean

```
    @Value("${resetPassword.email.key}")
    private String resetPassword;
```

Property file

```
resetPassword.email.key = RESET_PASSWORD
```

Constants.java

```
public static final String resetPassword_email_key = "RESET_PASSWORD";
```

Answer (score 5):

You can't reference java constant in properties file. And you don't need Spring injection for that. You simply do

```
private String resetPassword = Constants.resetPassword_email_key;
```

If you need to share `Constants` class between multiple sub-projects (modules of a project), you may want to extract this class to a library that may be included into other projects.

Comment: Spring is being used in my application and I cannot remove it.

Comment: @shivakumar So don't remove it. I just want to say that you don't need Spring to solve this particular problem.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot inject a value to static properties. But you can assign to non-static setter as below:

```
  @Component
public class GlobalValue {

   public static String DATABASE;

   @Value("${mongodb.db}")
  public void setDatabase(String db) {
      DATABASE = db;
   }

 }
```

From https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-inject-a-value-into-static-variables/

Comment: but property 'resetPassword' in my spring bean is non static.

Comment: @shivakumar: do you mean this one ? `public static final String resetPassword_email_key = "RESET_PASSWORD";`

Comment: @htpvl No, I think the OP means `private String resetPassword;`

Comment: @naXa: I see so your answer is correct. anyway, OP request's really weird :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can inject value with `@Value` from properties file or from spring bean.

To use properties file declare it with `util:properties` tag:

```
<util:properties id="jdbcProperties" location="classpath:org/example/config/jdbc.properties"/>
```

And in spring bean do :

```
private @Value("#{jdbcProperties.url}") String jdbcUrl;
    private @Value("#{jdbcProperties.username}") String username;
    private @Value("#{jdbcProperties.password}") String password;
```

Or you can inject value of another spring bean like:

```
@Value("#{strategyBean.databaseKeyGenerator}")
public void setKeyGenerator(KeyGenerator kg) { … }
```

More info at http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/new-in-3.html